# Seam parameterized @RaiseEvent annotation?

Tags: jsf, seam

is it possible to give an parameter to the `@RaiseEvent` annotation?

I have an observer

```
@Observer(value = { MyEvents.MY_EVENT }, create = false)
public void doSomething(String oldValue) {
```

when using the method call, i can give parameter with the raise `Events.instance().raiseEvent(MyEvents.MY_EVENT, name);`. is it possible to give that parameter also with the annotation? (i just like prefer the annotation to the method call)

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The `@RaiseEvent` annotation does not support parameters. 

If you want to use parameters you have to programatically raise an event.

```
Events.instance().raiseEvent("nameOfObserver",parameters...);
```